# Python implementation of LeetCode Minimum Size Subarray Sum problem using sliding window technique

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to solve the leetcode problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum/description/

```
class Solution:
    def minSubArrayLen(self, target: int, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        head=0
        tail=len(nums)-1
        totalval=sum(nums)
        if totalval<target:
            return 0
        if totalval==target:
            return len(nums)
        while 1:
            if nums[head] > nums[tail]:
                totalval=totalval-nums[tail]
                if totalval<target:
                    break
                tail=tail-1

            if nums[head] <= nums[tail]:
                totalval=totalval-nums[head]
                if totalval<target:
                    break
                head=head+1          
        diff=tail-head
        return diff+1
```

My apporach is to get the sum of the whole array and have 2 pointers pointing
at the beginning and the end of the array.
While moving the head or tail pointer toward center depends on which one is smaller, I am also updating the sum too.

I managed to pass 18 out of 20 test cases but stuck at the 19th test case.
[test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WTFt.png)
I am guessing either I have logic error in my code or the entire algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: this is giving first item for which `totalval<target`, not minimum  length subarray